# Next day of the user entered date - date +1 day

Tags: ksh, date, aix

I am new to scripting. I need a script in the AIX environment to get the next days date based on the date entered by the user.

After hard time browsing for this, I got a piece of code which does the reverse of the goal which i had to achieve.
It gets me one day before (yesterday) the date entered by the user.

The code is this

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Enter the date (YYYY/MM/DD):"
read date
YEAR=`echo $date | cut -d"/" -f1`
MONTH=`echo $date | cut -d"/" -f2`
DAY=`echo $date | cut -d"/" -f3`
DAY=`expr "$DAY" - 1`
case "$DAY" in
0)
MONTH=`expr "$MONTH" - 1`
case "$MONTH" in
0)
MONTH=12
YEAR=`expr "$YEAR" - 1`
;;
esac
DAY=`cal $MONTH $YEAR | grep . | fmt -1 | tail -1`
esac
echo "Yesterday's Date is $YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY"
```

Can someone please help achieve to get the next day of the user entered date.

Desired Output:

```
Enter the date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2013/09/30

Tomorrow's Date is 2013/10/1
```

Answer (score 2):

With relatively recent versions of `ksh93`:

```
$ printf "%(%Y/%m/%d)T\n" "2014/06/20 +1 day"
2014/06/21
```

Or:

```
$ printf "%(%Y/%m/%d)T\n" "2014/06/20 next day"
2014/06/21  
$ printf "%(%Y/%m/%d)T\n" "2014/06/20 tomorrow"
2014/06/21
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure AIX does not have GNU date by default. Depending on your version of perl, you can do:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -le '
    $tomorrow = Time::Piece->strptime($ARGV[0], "%Y/%m/%d") + ONE_DAY;
    print $tomorrow->ymd("/")
' 2013/10/28
```

So, in ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
read date?"Enter the date (YYYY/MM/DD): "
tomorrow=$(
    perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -le '
        $tomorrow = Time::Piece->strptime($ARGV[0], "%Y/%m/%d") + ONE_DAY;
        print $tomorrow->ymd("/")
    ' "$date"
)
echo "Tomorrow is $tomorrow"
```

Running this looks like:

```
Enter the date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2013/12/31
Tomorrow is 2014/01/01
```

Tested on an old version of ksh and perl

```
$ what /usr/bin/ksh
/usr/bin/ksh:
        Version M-11/16/88i
        SunOS 5.8 Generic 110662-24 Apr 2007
$ perl --version

This is perl, v5.10.0 built for sun4-solaris
```

Comment: No input validation is performed here, so if the user enters an invalid date format, perl will complain.

Comment: :I dont have perl modules installed in the machine I use. So is there any way to achieve this without perl.

Comment: Did you check? I believe that Time::Piece and Time::Seconds are core Perl modules.

Comment: Yes. I had tried it earlier I was getting  perl modules not found errors. I do not have admin access for that machine to install the perl modules.

Comment: :Can you please help me to edit the above piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Perl approach, with just a very basic/common modules (`Time::Local` and `POSIX`):

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Enter the date (YYYY/MM/DD):"
read date
timestamp=`perl -MTime::Local=timelocal -e '@t = split(/[-\/]/, $ARGV[0]); $t[1]--; print timelocal(1,1,1,reverse @t);' $date`
YESTERDAY=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y/%m/%d", localtime($ARGV[0] -86400));' $timestamp`
TODAY=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y/%m/%d", localtime($ARGV[0]));' $timestamp`
TOMORROW=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y/%m/%d", localtime($ARGV[0] +86400));' $timestamp`
echo "YESTERDAY= $YESTERDAY"
echo "TODAY= $TODAY"
echo "TOMORROW= $TOMORROW"
```

Example:

```
Enter the date (YYYY/MM/DD):
2014/02/28
YESTERDAY= 2014/02/27
TODAY= 2014/02/28
TOMORROW= 2014/03/01
```

If don't have the `Time::Local` module, this can still be done with a bit more of pain. However, the `POSIX` module (`strftime` method) is mandatory as being the "smart" part of the thing. Without it, it would be difficult to go from "28-feb" to "01-mar".

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

```
currDate=$(date); nextDay=$(date -d "$currDate + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d"); echo "$nextDay"
```

Comment: Not on AIX you can't. This would work on Linux.

Comment: Oh I totally missed AIX.It would be a matter of looking at the `date` manual on AIX.

Comment: Be my guest: [the date manual on AIX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/date.htm)

Answer (score -1):

```
printf "Enter the date (YYYY/MM/DD):" ; read user_date

desired_date=`date --date="$user_date+1 day" +"%Y/%m/%d"`

echo "Tomorrow's Date is $desired_date"
```

Comment: Not on AIX you can't. This would work on Linux.