# Display lines in last 10 minutes with specific pattern in logs

Tags: awk, grep, logs, date, aix

I need to display lines with Error occurred in last 10 minutes of a log file.

```
Aug 26 10:50:42 Normal line.
Aug 26 10:51:23 Normal line.
Aug 26 10:55:33 Error line.
Aug 26 10:56:45 Normal line.
Aug 26 10:58:12 Error line.
Aug 26 11:02:31 Normal line.
Aug 26 11:03:32 Normal line.
Aug 26 11:04:11 Normal line.
```

Suppose above sample of log file. I want to display only following two lines

```
Aug 26 10:55:33 Error line.
Aug 26 10:58:12 Error line.
```

I am using AIX.

Comment: Potential answerers note that [AIX's stock `date` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/date.htm) does not support arbitrary dates as input.

Comment: Is Perl available?

Comment: When you say "last 10 minutes of a log file" do you mean relative to the last datestamp in the file, or relative to the time you're running the command?

Comment: Related only: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265951/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller I mean relative to the time im running the command. CURRENT SYSTEM TIME i mean.

Answer (score 2):

With a hat tip to Stéphane Chazelas for their two answers here:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265953
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140890

I propose a brute-force solution that loops over every possible timestamp entry for the past 10 minutes:

```
#!/bin/ksh93
for((i=0;i<=600;i++))
do
  d=$(printf '%(%b %d %H:%M:%S)T\n' "$i seconds ago")
  grep "^${d} Error" logfile
done
```

It's brute-force because it calls `grep` (and printf, a built-in) 601 times. It requires a ksh93 that supports the printf `%T` option for printing (and formatting) arbitrary timestamps. It's easier than doing date math on your own, though, because of edge cases such as:

- day boundaries
- month boundaries
- possible daylight-savings changes

Answer (score 1):

A possibility here, shamelessly ripping off @Jeff Schaller's solution.  Single invocation of `grep`, so maybe a little faster.

```
#!/bin/ksh93
for((i=0;i<=600;i++))
do
  d=$(printf '%s|%(%b %d %H:%M:%S)T' "${d}" "${i} seconds ago")
done
grep -E "^(${d:1}) Error" logfile
```

Comment: [AIX grep](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/grep.htm) does have -E.

Comment: Moving the Error string to the grep command would save some repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses i did the required work with following command.

```
awk -v d1="$d1" -v d2="$d2" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' logfile
```

where d1 and d2 were initialized above. Did the job for me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get last 10 minutes lines every 10 minutes, you can use the [cutthelog](https://github.com/yaznahar/cutthelog/tree/main) tool which allow to print an unseen tailing part of a log file. First you save the file position by command

```
$ cutthelog logfile > /dev/null
```

then process the log by cron job e.g.

```
*/10 * * * * root cutthelog logfile | grep 'Error line' | ..."
```

As a extra benefit you get rid of reading the whole log on each check.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that while this tool seems to allow restricting log view to the part of the file newly added since the last invocation, it does not allow to restrict the view to a certain amount of time nor does it allow pattern matching. As such, this proposal doesn't seem to address the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).